# how to build wget progress bar in Node JS for downloading files?

Tags: node.js

I am writing a command line tool, which downloads a software from the net. `request` and `request-progress` modules to download. The code is below(same as official documented one). 
Now I want to show the progress of download something similar to `wget` download progress bar?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var progress = require('request-progress');

// The options argument is optional so you can omit it 
progress(request('https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox/IE11/Windows/IE11.Win8.1.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip'), {
    // throttle: 2000,                    // Throttle the progress event to 2000ms, defaults to 1000ms 
    // delay: 1000,                       // Only start to emit after 1000ms delay, defaults to 0ms 
    // lengthHeader: 'x-transfer-length'  // Length header to use, defaults to content-length 
})
.on('progress', function (state) {
    // The state is an object that looks like this: 
    // { 
    //     percent: 0.5,               // Overall percent (between 0 to 1) 
    //     speed: 554732,              // The download speed in bytes/sec 
    //     size: { 
    //         total: 90044871,        // The total payload size in bytes 
    //         transferred: 27610959   // The transferred payload size in bytes 
    //     }, 
    //     time: { 
    //         elapsed: 36.235,        // The total elapsed seconds since the start (3 decimals) 
    //         remaining: 81.403       // The remaining seconds to finish (3 decimals) 
    //     } 
    // } 
    console.log('progress', state);
})
.on('error', function (err) {
    // Do something with err 
})
.on('end', function () {
    // Do something after request finishes 
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('IE11.Win8.1.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip'));
```

Progress bar for above program
[image: Progress bar for above program]

How to get the progress bar some this similar to `wget` in nodejs? Simply to understand I added `wget` screenshots for same file download. It's simple and efficient.
[image: wget progress bar-1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example but not polished, you might need to tweak some stuff:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
const progress = require('request-progress');
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const filename = 'IE11.Win8.1.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip';

progress(request('https://az412801.vo.msecnd.net/vhd/VMBuild_20141027/VirtualBox/IE11/Windows/IE11.Win8.1.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip'), {
})
.on('progress', function (state) {
  readline.clearLine(rl, 0);
  readline.cursorTo(rl, 0);
  rl.write(statusBar(filename, state));
})
.on('error', function (err) {
    // Do something with err 
})
.on('end', function () {
    // Do something after request finishes 
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));


function statusBar(filename, progress) {
  let str = `${filename}    `;
  str += progressBar(progress.percent);
  str += stats(progress);
  return str;
}

function progressBar(percent) {
  percent = Math.floor(percent * 100);
  let str = `%${percent}[`;
  str += '='.repeat(percent);
  str += '>'
  str += ' '.repeat(99 - percent);
  str += '] ';
  return str
}

function stats({speed, size, time}) {
  const sizeM = Math.round(size.transferred / 1024)
  const speedMb = Math.round(speed * 0.000008)
  const eta = new Date(time.remaining * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
  return `${sizeM}M ${speedMb}MB/s eta ${eta}`;
}
```

### NOTE:

I'm using some ES6 features, like:

- [String.prototype.repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)
- [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (on the function stats)

I think the code is self explanatory, make sure you give a look at the [readline docs](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline)

**Screenshot:**

[image: wget progress bar in node]